# How to set username in connection using Signalr in Windows Store app

Tags: authentication, windows-store-apps, signalr, signalr-hub

i'm using SignalrR in a Windows Store app using HTML5/Javascript.

I would like to pass username and password to my signalR hub.

My code so far:

```
connection = $.connection.hub;
connection.url = "http://******/signalr";

gamehub = $.connection.game;
connection.start(function () {
     console.log('connection started!');
})
```

And it works, the connection is okay, i can call the hub's functions, and i can get the answers. However i would like to authenticate the user, so pass some info in the connection.

I tried to set header, but since its XSS, it's not a working option.
Setting a cookie is a not an option either in windows store apps as i understand.

Please help me, how can i pass the credentials to the hub.

Thanks